# How do I split input texts with multiple delimiters?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

> Update: The problem has been solved! Thanks everyone for helping!

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
Title: The Importance of Being Earnest
       A Trivial Comedy for Serious People


Author: Oscar Wilde
```

I would like to split the text via "(space)\t\n\r\f", any other tokens such as ",.:" will be regarded as part of the words. Are there any efficient ways that I can split the tokens like so?

I tried this:

```
public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString(), "\t");
```

I know you can split the tokens by a tab, is there a way to split the tokens by more than one delimiter?

Comment: Don't use the very old class `StringTokenizer` but have a look at `String.split(regex)`. The regex you'd be after would be `\s`, i.e. the character class for whitespace which would be equivalent to `[ \t\r\n\f]` - so `String[] tokens = value.toString().split("\\s");` should do the trick.

Comment: Or use Pattern.compile(<your-regex>) to extract the matched groups directly.

Comment: Thank you everyone, I will try and update once my question has been resolved!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.split()` and separate all possible delimiters by `"|"`. Note that some delimiters need to be escaped (e.g. `"."` -> `"\\."`)

**Example**:

```
String input = "123,45!67.890";

String[] splitted = input.split(",|\\.|!");
for (String split : splitted) {
    System.out.println(split);
}
```

**Output**:

```
123
45
67
890
```

Comment: instead of `|`, the so called [Character Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#simple) `[ ]` can be used (e.g. `split("[,.!]")` for code posted in this answer; the question is about splitting at whitespace characters)